# Add elements inside Array conditionally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I try to merge two objects using the spread operator conditionally, it works when the condition is `true` or `false`:

```
let condition = false;
let obj1 = { key1: 'value1'}
let obj2 = {
  key2: 'value2',
  ...(condition && obj1),
};

// obj2 = {key2: 'value2'};
```

When I try to use the same logic with Arrays, it only works when the condition is `true`:

```
let condition = true;
let arr1 = ['value1'];
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(condition && arr1)];

// arr2 = ['value2', 'value1']
```

If the condition is `false` an error is thrown:

```js
let condition = false;
let arr1 = ['value1'];
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(condition && arr1)];

// Error
```

Why is the behaviour different between `Array` and `Object`?

Comment: Not cleared. What do you want to achieve here? Can you please paste your `(condition && arr)` as well?

Comment: FYI, `{ ...null }` and `{ ...undefined }` won't throw error either. So, we can forgo that check as well if we are unsure if an object has value or not

Comment: FWIW if you wanted to spread booleans, you could do something like `Boolean.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {}` (obviously don't do this in production code, it's a mere curio)

Comment: Is what you really want to achieve `condition ? [...arr1, ...arr2] : arr1` or is this just a question on how the language works?

Comment: @JollyJoker it's just a question on how the language works. Thanks

Answer (score 96, accepted):

When you spread into an *array*, you call the `Symbol.iterator` method on the object. `&&` evaluates to the first falsey value (or the last truthy value, if all are truthy), so

```
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(condition && arr)];
```

results in

```
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(false)];
```

But `false` does not have a `Symbol.iterator` method.

You could use the conditional operator instead, and spread an empty array if the condition is false:

```js
let condition = false;
let arr1 = ['value1'];
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(condition ? arr1 : [])];
console.log(arr2);
```

(This works because the empty array *does* have the `Symbol.iterator` method)

Object spread is *completely* different: it copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object. `false` does not have any own enumerable properties, so nothing gets copied.

Answer (score 25):

**`false` is not spreadable.**

You need a spreadable object (the one where [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) is implemented) which returns nothing, if spreaded.

You could use an empty array as default value. This works even if `arr` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```js
let condition = false;
let arr1 = ['value1'];
let arr2 = ['value2', ...condition && arr || []];

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: would add parenthesis to make it clearer `((condition && arr) || [])`

Comment: This could really use the `?:` operator instead of a chained `||`.

Comment: @deceze, it really depends on the use case.

Comment: I think *this* is a use case where `?:` is a lot more appropriate. ;)

Comment: Couple of points:

Should have used `const arr1 ....`, `const arr2 ...` instead of `var`. Can be simplified to: `const arr2 = ['value2', ...(condiition ? ['value1'] : [])];`

Answer (score 13):

This is a specification difference between the spread syntax for object literals and for array literals.

MDN briefly mentions it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Only_for_iterables) -- I highlight:

> Spread syntax (***other than in the case of spread properties***) can be applied only to iterable objects

The difference comes from the EcmaScript 2018 specification:

- Concerning object spread syntax, see [12.2.6.8 Runtime Semantics: PropertyDefinitionEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation):

  - It calls `CopyDataProperties(object, fromValue, excludedNames)` where the *fromValue* is wrapped to an object with `ToObject`, and therefore becomes iterable, even if *fromValue* is a primitive value like `false`. Therefore `{...false}` is **valid** EcmaScript.
- Concerning array spread syntax, see [12.2.5.2 Runtime Semantics: ArrayAccumulation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation):

  - It merely calls `GetValue(spreadRef)` which does not do the above mentioned wrapping. And so the subsequent call to `GetIterator` will trigger an error on a primitive value, as it is not iterable. Therefore `[...false]` is **invalid** EcmaScript.

Answer (score 3):

**Example with objects:**

```
 const lessonMenuItems = [
  ...(true
    ? [
        {
          value: 'post',
        },
      ]
    : []),
  {
    value: 'assign',
  },
]
```

Result:

```
lessonMenuItems = [
  {
    value: 'post',
  },
  {
    value: 'assign',
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (? :) and put an empty array as the false

```js
let condition = false;
let arr1 = ['value1'];
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(condition ? arr1 : [])];
console.log(arr2);
```